# Windows 8.1 application. Image button "Settings"

Tags: c#, windows, settings

I have simple application for Windows 8.1 (C#). It has one page and I want to add programmatically standard image button "Settings".
Is it possible to use a standard static image resource for the button?

```
Button btnSettings = new Button();
btnSettings.Height = 50; // will be as image size
btnSettings.Width = 50;
//btnSettings.Content = "TEST";
Canvas.Children.Add(btnSettings); // I have big Canvas object
btnSettings.UpdateLayout();
Canvas.SetTop(btnSettings, 0);
Canvas.SetLeft(btnSettings, dx - btnSettings.ActualWidth); // dx - canvas width
//btnSettings.Style = ???
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I button is a ContentControl you can specify a child image with its source
From: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj153346.aspx#Y778

So just add a child image control to the button and set its source. This is the xaml approach to show you - but you'd do this in code.

```
<Button Click="Button_Click_1" 
        Background="#FF0D6AA3" 
        Height="100" Width="100" >
    <StackPanel>
        <Image Source="Assets/Banana.png"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Banana" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Setting the image source is as follows:

```
Image img = new Image();
img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Logo.png"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. It was wrong way.
To create a settings page use this [link](http://irisclasson.com/2014/02/07/implementing-a-settingsflyout-settings-pane-in-windows-store-apps-8-1/).
So user can call to system pane by move mouse cursor to right top or bottom screen corener and select "Settings" menu item.
In the pane user can click on link "MySettings".